# Download audio file

Tags: java

Maybe I'm blind or stupid, but after 30 minutes of browsing I haven't found anything helpful...

I want to download an audio file (with pronunciation of a word - it plays when you click on one of those 2 flags in the left) from [thefreedicitonary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/word)
It is embedded (if i understand it properly) as a flash object this way:

```
<object codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com...>
<param name="movie" value="http://img.tfd.com/m/sound.swf"><param name="menu" value="false">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<param name="FlashVars" value="sound_src=http://img2.tfd.com/pron/mp3/en/US/dg/dgsysksfdyht.mp3&amp;image_src=http://img.tfd.com/m/flags/18_US.jpg">
<embed style="margin:0 0 0 3px;" src="http://img.tfd.com/m/sound.swf" flashvars="sound_src=http://img2.tfd.com/pron/mp3/en/US/dg/dgsysksfdyht.mp3&amp;image_src=http://img.tfd.com/m/flags/18_US.jpg" menu="false" width="28" height="18" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></object>
```

, so when I download the HTML file there isn't a sign of any mp3 link :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td id=MainTitle nowrap><h1>word <script>playV2('en/US/dg/dgsysksfdyht');playV2('en/UK/dg/dgsysksfdyht')</script> </h1></td>
```

### Code

```
class SoundURL {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // let us assume you are able to trim it down to this..
        String script = "playV2('en/US/dg/dgsysksfdyht')";

        String prefix = "http://img2.tfd.com/pron/mp3/";
        String suffix = ".mp3";

        int start = script.indexOf("'");
        int end = script.indexOf("'", start+1);

        String path = script.substring(start+1,end);
        String urlString = prefix + path + suffix;

        System.out.println(urlString);
    }
}
```

### Output

```
http://img2.tfd.com/pron/mp3/en/US/dg/dgsysksfdyht.mp3
Press any key to continue . . .
```

### Notes

You will need to:

1. Parse the HTML using an HTML parser.  Using `String` manipulation methods only works for trivially simple strings.
2. ***Check that the site allows such use or their resources.***

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that, but I appreciate your effort, so you get the tick :) They accept only browser requests, so that's easy to bypass. Btw I'm using HTMLCleaner, which is a very easy-to-use tool.

Answer (score 2):

1. It seems to be embedded in Flash. That's why there is no direct link.
2. It Seems to be `http://img2.tfd.com/pron/mp3/en/US/dg/dgsysksfdyht.mp3` in the `embed` tags  `flashvars` attribute. You could just parse that :-)

Comment: but how to? Whe I download the HTML source through URLConnection there isn't any <embed...

Comment: <td id=MainTitle nowrap><h1>word  <script>playV2('en/US/dg/dgsysksfdyht');playV2('en/UK/dg/dgsysksfdyht')</script> </h1></td>

Comment: just this <script>, the <object> is missing

Comment: I cannot tell you why that is, now. My browser behaves differently. Sorry. But you could use this `en/US/dg/dgsysksfdyht` String for the time being to build the URL.

Comment: I don't understand this behavior either. But the browser kinda creates the <object ...<embed code from the sctipt. Thank you